# error: cannot convert 'float (*)[b]' to 'float**' for argument '3' to 'void

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
void add_element(char *tablenameadd, 
                 char headladd[][16], 
                 float **tableadd, 
                 int hcols, 
                 int trows, 
                 int tcols)
{
    ...
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    add_element(tname, 
                headl, 
                arr1, 
                hlb, 
                a, 
                b);
}
```

> error: cannot convert 'float (*)[b]' to 'float**' for argument '3' to 'void add_element'.

I want to pass an unspecified or variable two dimensional array to a function.

`arr1` is imported from a file, with an unknown amount of columns and rows until imported, consisting of usual float table data. `a` are rows and `b` are columns of `arr1`.

Comment: Please edit your question, and format it properly, as well as showing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to  [edit] your questions to improve them, for example by showing a [mcve].

Comment: As for a ***guess*** about the problem, while an array can decay to a pointer to its first element, an array of arrays will decay to a pointer to an array (as the first element is an array) *not* a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: not enough in example to guess...  as written tname, head1, arr1, h1b, a, and b are not defined...     I assume from your text that b  is the problem... but you didnt show how it is defined... so we cant assist in finding the issue with it.

Comment: the arr1 is imported prior from a file with a unknown amount of columns and rows until imported
consisting of usual float table data

Comment: *the arr1 is imported prior from a file with a unknown amount of columns and rows* -- Let's see this in C++ code.  A `float **tableadd` is not a two-dimensional array.  This is a pointer to a `float *`.  The "array" you must pass to it has to also be created starting with a `float **`, or it is a `float*` and you're passing the address of it.

Comment: not able to to post that much code function reads each char solely from the file and saves it in an 2D float array - thought were possible to pass it directly to the further function without converting it to 1D and back to 2D again as an array...

Comment: Another possible issue: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) You can solve that problem (as well as the one you're asking about) by using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

converted the 2D array in a 1D Array passed it to the function and converted it back to a 2D array

---

```
float arradd[trows][tcols];

int as=0, a=0, b=0;

while(as<=(tcols*trows))
{
  arradd[a][b]=tableadd[as];
  as=as+1;
  if(a==trows)
  {
    a=0;
    b=b+1;
  }
  else
  {
    a=a+1;
  }
}
```